# How to save jvcsvdata WITHOUT double quotes

Tags: jedi

It seems that whenever I load and save (savetofile) a jvCsvData ... double quotes end up in the results. How can I override this and FORCE 'no double quotes' in the saved results ???

Comment: Please post your code se we can see what might be wrong.

Comment: I've tried multiple combinations though.  Basically, the ONLY difference is that I am not defining the fields at all. ( so implicitly jvcsvdataset will turn all fields into strings ). For this project, I will never know how many columns I have on any given file. So when i use the "SavetoFile, or ExportToCsv" method, all strings receive a double quote around them. I need to 'not' have this happen.

Comment: I've even tried using a Tmemo or TStringList with a "AssignToStrings / AssignFromStrings" and a StringReplace Command - and the data just gets screwed up.

Comment: Ive tried using a filestream to read, then stringreplace, then save - and no luck. The whole issue is,... How can i open up a csv file and remove all double quotes,... successfully. all methods have failed thus far.